# List of lists of dictionaries with the same keys but different values

Tags: python

I need to collect certain key/value pairs from logs from the antivirus. I’ve been able to collect all key/value pairs I need except for one, the action taken by the antivirus.
Everything revolves around the ‘indicators’ key, which contains a list of dicts with each containing a certain piece of information about the virus/malware found. Each of these dicts starts with an id number (1,2,3,4…) which varies depending on the virus/malware. While these dicts have the exact same structure (and same key names), their values differ. Take a gander at the excerpt below:

```
"indicators": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "detection_name",
                "field": "malName",
                "value": "HKTL_CAIN",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "type": "file_sha1",
                "field": "fileHash",
                "value": "",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "type": "filename",
                "field": "fileName",
                "value": "D:\\ECIH",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "type": "fullpath",
                "field": "fullPath",
                "value": "D:\\ECIH",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "type": "text",
                "field": "actResult",
                "value": "File cleaned",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "type": "text",
                "field": "scanType",
                "value": "Scheduled Scan",
                "relatedEntities": [
                    "C888A5B2"
                ],
                "filterIds": [
                    "a665ee2c"
                ],
                "provenance": [
                    "Alert"
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Note that id 1 relates to the malware name. Id 2 is the hash value, id 3 is the file name, etc. What I'm interested in is in id 5, which contains the action taken by the antivirus. There is a long list of possible actions, but for exemplification purposes, the actions are `'File cleaned'` and `'File quarantined.'` The action is always found in the key `'value'`, but the problem is that `'value'` appears everywhere. I noticed that the 'value' I need (server action) is always paired with the `'actResult'` value in the `'field'`, which also appears everywhere.

```
        {
            "id": 5,
            "type": "text",
            "field": "actResult",
            "value": "File cleaned",
            "relatedEntities": [
                "C888A5B2"
            ],
            "filterIds": [
                "a665ee2c"
            ],
            "provenance": [
                "Alert"
            ]
        }
```

Another issue is that these logs aren't always the same length, so some have id1, id2,..id5 whereas others might have 11 ids. Nothing is consistent. Regardless, what I need to do is to capture the values I need and put them into a dataframe, but given that the 'value' key appears everywhere, the script is faulty.

In the sample I provide, there are 10 records total, so I'll have 10 IDs. But since the info on the virus changes based on the virus type, so do the 'indicators'. Hence, where a record is missing, I replace it with a ' - '. But since the 'value' key appears everywhere, I end up with an uneven number of ID/Action.

Please refer to the log here (https://codeshare.io/j0yX1A). The script is below:

```
actions = ['File cleaned', 'File deleted', 'File quarantined']
actions_list = []
action_list = []

id = [id['id'] for id in logs]
print(id)

for log in logs:
        for indicator in log['indicators']:
                if indicator['value'] in actions:
                        action_list.append(indicator['value'])
                    else:
                                action_list.append('-')
print(action_list)
```

Current output:
[image]

As you can see, the current script picks up all 'value' keys rather than just the ones whose values are in the actions list.

Expected Output

If there is no key/value, replace it with a ' - '.

```
['WB-13273-20230604-00000', 'WB-13273-20230603-00000', 'WB-13273-20230601-00001', 'WB-13273-20230601-00000', 'WB-13273-20230529-00000', 'WB-13273-20230526-00000', 'WB-13273-20230523-00001', 'WB-13273-20230523-00000', 'WB-13273-20230510-00002', 'WB-13273-20230510-00003']
[' - ',' - ','File cleaned', 'File cleaned', ' - ','File cleaned', ' - ','File quarantined', 'File quarantined', 'File quarantined']
```

Same number of IDs and actions.

So how can I collect the action value from the "field" key and replace the missing records with a ' - ' while ignoring the other 'value' keys that aren't needed?

Comment: So... what's your question? You never asked any. Also, don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Didn't you already ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407660/list-of-lists-of-dictionaries-with-inconsistent-keys) with nearly the exact same title and contents? Nobody answered your original question because nobody can understand what you were asking. Reposting the same thing over and over won't get it fixed if your question is bad. If you're trying to update your question and make it better, use the [edit] function instead of making a new post.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I rephrased the entire post. Perhaps it's clear now.

Comment: Because creating an MRE is difficult doesn't mean you can forgo the exercise.  We need a sample set of data in order to test any solution and to reproduce the problem encountered.

Comment: @itprorh66 Did you actually read my post? The sample is provided in an external link because if put it in my post pedantic people complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be looking for the `else` clause of the `for` loop to account for the cases where you have not "actResults". I call this the `no break` clause as the `else` is what happens in the event that the `for` loop did not do a `break`.

Given [your data](https://codeshare.io/j0yX1A):

```py
import json

with open("log.json", "r") as file_in:
    log_data = json.load(file_in)

action_list = []
for log_entry in log_data:
    for indicator in log_entry["indicators"]:
        if indicator.get("field") == "actResult":
            action_list.append((log_entry["id"], indicator["value"]))
            break
    else:
        action_list.append((log_entry["id"], "--"))

for action in action_list:
    print(action)
```

Will give you back your list of 10:

```
('WB-13273-20230601-00001', '--')
('WB-13273-20230601-00000', '--')
('WB-13273-20230529-00000', '--')
('WB-13273-20230526-00000', 'File cleaned')
('WB-13273-20230523-00001', '--')
('WB-13273-20230523-00000', '--')
('WB-13273-20230510-00002', 'File quarantined')
('WB-13273-20230510-00003', 'File quarantined')
('WB-13273-20230510-00001', 'File quarantined')
('WB-13273-20230510-00000', 'File quarantined')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```py
actions_to_track = ['File cleaned', 'File deleted', 'File quarantined']

def get_actresult(log):
    for ind in log['indicators']:
        if ind.get('field') == 'actResult':  # an action indicator
            if ind.get('value') in actions_to_track:
                return ind.get('value')

    return '-'

log_ids_to_actresult = {log['id']: get_actresult(log) for log in logs}
# => {'example_id_0': 'File cleaned'}
```

Running against `logs` from https://codeshare.io/j0yX1A, this produces:

```py
{
  'WB-13273-20230510-00000': 'File quarantined',
  'WB-13273-20230510-00001': 'File quarantined',
  'WB-13273-20230510-00002': 'File quarantined',
  'WB-13273-20230510-00003': 'File quarantined',
  'WB-13273-20230523-00000': '-',
  'WB-13273-20230523-00001': '-',
  'WB-13273-20230526-00000': 'File cleaned',
  'WB-13273-20230529-00000': '-',
  'WB-13273-20230601-00000': '-',
  'WB-13273-20230601-00001': '-',
}
```

However, I'm not sure because your question is unclear and missing key information. My answer is based on the following guesses I've had to make that you should've clarified in your question:

---

1. You've got a list of `log` dictionaries, each with `"id"` and `"indicators"` keys
2. There are a variable number of indicators per log. They are all `dict` of the same format
3. An "action indicator" will have a `"field"` of `"actResult"`
4. For each log, you want to extract the `"value"` from an action indicator if it exists and if the value is one of an explicit list of actions you care about, otherwise use `"-"`
5. The actResult values you care about are `['File cleaned', 'File deleted', 'File quarantined']`

A complete but minimal-ish example of the logs and indicator data is:

```py
logs = [
    {
        "id": "example_id_0",
        "indicators": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "detection_name",
                "field": "malName",
                "value": "HKTL_CAIN",
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "type": "text",
                "field": "actResult",
                "value": "File cleaned",
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: I like the use of a dictionary here to tie the action to the id as well as the use of a method to early return rather than my `for/else`. Clean and tidy.

Comment: Several others have also tried helping you improve your question, despite you being rude and taking criticism so personally. The script works fine against your posted codeshare data (see produced output), so you've likely made some mistake.